# Mercurial hook for pretag

Tags: mercurial

I want to force a policy (based on a regex) on tag names while committing the code to mercurial. After searching a lot I found the below sample.

```
version_re = r'(ver-\d+\.\d+\.\d+|tip)$'
def invalidtag(ui, repo, hooktype, node, **kwargs):
assert(hooktype == 'pretag')

....


if not re_.match(tag):
    ui.warn('Invalid tag name "%s".\n' % tag)
    return True
return False
```

My question is, how can I get the tag name from repo which is being committed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec%3ahook%3apretag), the tag name is passed in along with the hook so I think that changing your hook definition to this might work:

```
def invalidtag(ui, repo, hooktype, node, tag, **kwargs):
```